# Convert list of dictionaries to separate list based on dictionary values

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I have my JSON Structure like this, I wish to create new list by checking `driverKey` of each dictionary inside list

```
{
  "RDBMS": [
    {
      "userName": "a",
      "entityName": "entity1",
      "connectionString": "DRIVER={PostgreSQL Unicode};DATABASE=database1;UID=uid1;PWD=password;SERVER=127.0.0.1;SID=null;PORT=5432;",
      "databaseName": "database1",
      "driverKey": "PostgreSQL Unicode"
    },
    {
      "userName": "b",
      "entityName": "entity2",
      "connectionString": "DRIVER={PostgreSQL Unicode};DATABASE=database1;UID=uid1;PWD=password;SERVER=127.0.0.1;SID=null;PORT=5432;",
      "databaseName": "database1",
      "driverKey": "PostgreSQL Unicode"
    },
    {
      "userName": "a",
      "entityName": "entity3",
      "connectionString": "DRIVER={PostgreSQL Unicode};DATABASE=database1;UID=uid1;PWD=password;SERVER=127.0.0.1;SID=null;PORT=5432;",
      "databaseName": "database1",
      "driverKey": "SQL Server"
    }
  ]
}
```

Expected Output:

```
{
  "PostgreSQL": [
    {
      "userName": "a",
      "entityName": "entity1",
      "connectionString": "DRIVER={PostgreSQL Unicode};DATABASE=database1;UID=uid1;PWD=password;SERVER=127.0.0.1;SID=null;PORT=5432;",
      "databaseName": "database1",
      "driverKey": "PostgreSQL Unicode"
    },
    {
      "userName": "b",
      "entityName": "entity2",
      "connectionString": "DRIVER={PostgreSQL Unicode};DATABASE=database1;UID=uid1;PWD=password;SERVER=127.0.0.1;SID=null;PORT=5432;",
      "databaseName": "database1",
      "driverKey": "PostgreSQL Unicode"
    }
 ],
 "SQL SERVER": [
    {
      "userName": "a",
      "entityName": "entity1",
      "connectionString": "DRIVER={PostgreSQL Unicode};DATABASE=database1;UID=uid1;PWD=password;SERVER=127.0.0.1;SID=null;PORT=5432;",
      "databaseName": "database1",
      "driverKey": "PostgreSQL Unicode"
    }]

}
```

I have tried different approach but `"connectionString"` inside my dictionary gives me different output.
loop over list and getting item does not solve my problem. Any Suggestions

Comment: Is "RDBMS" the only key in your input?

Comment: yes as of now  @COLDSPEED

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need two loops. One per key, and another one for each list value per key. Append to a new dictionary per iteration.

```
data = {'RDBMS' : [...]}
```

```
new_data = {}
for k in data:
    for l in data[k]:
        new_data.setdefault(l["driverKey"].split()[0], []).append(l)
```

Alternatively, use a `defaultdict`:

```
from collections import defaultdict

new_data = defaultdict(list)
for k in data:
    for l in data[k]:
        new_data[l["driverKey"].split()[0]].append(l)
```

The defaultdict is slightly more efficient for a lot of data (the `dict.setdefault` unnecessarily creates and returns lists regardless of whether or not it has to at each turn).

Based on your comments, the outer loop isn't necessary, but it's always good to write code that won't easily break when your input changes.

```
print(new_data)
{
    'PostgreSQL': [{
        'userName': 'a',
        'entityName': 'entity1',
        'connectionString': 'DRIVER={PostgreSQL Unicode};DATABASE=database1;UID=uid1;PWD=password;SERVER=127.0.0.1;SID=null;PORT=5432;',
        'databaseName': 'database1',
        'driverKey': 'PostgreSQL Unicode'
    }, {
        'userName': 'b',
        'entityName': 'entity2',
        'connectionString': 'DRIVER={PostgreSQL Unicode};DATABASE=database1;UID=uid1;PWD=password;SERVER=127.0.0.1;SID=null;PORT=5432;',
        'databaseName': 'database1',
        'driverKey': 'PostgreSQL Unicode'
    }],
    'SQL': [{
        'userName': 'a',
        'entityName': 'entity3',
        'connectionString': 'DRIVER={PostgreSQL Unicode};DATABASE=database1;UID=uid1;PWD=password;SERVER=127.0.0.1;SID=null;PORT=5432;',
        'databaseName': 'database1',
        'driverKey': 'SQL Server'
    }]
}
```

Comment: the output result json in not correct  because of "connectionString"

Comment: @Roshan I don't get it. Is that not how it is in the input provided? This does not seem different from your expected output at all

Comment: @COLDSPEED  If we check result in json parser, it is scrambled, I am try to figure out that can we get output which is json serialisable. Thanks for quick response

Comment: @Roshan Yes, I see the problem. Dictionaries are not ordered on python versions below 3.6. Because of this, your data has no ordering. If you switch to python3.6, you will get your output in the same order. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Sorry But I am not worried about order ,I am creating new dict base on driverKey and the output is not in json readable format.. I am check output here : http://json.parser.online.fr/

Comment: @Roshan Yeah, it's not, because it's not JSON, it's a dictionary. You'll have to dump it to JSON before you validate it: `import json; json_data = json.dumps(new_data)`. You can validate `json_data`. By the way, this is identical to your expected output, so I don't know what else to say.

Answer (score 1):

to create a dict, you have iterate items and then assign to the unique key.

```
v = your_dict

output = {}
for l in v["RDBMS"]:
# check if key exists. if not create a list, to store multiple items
    if l["driverKey"] not in output:
        output[l["driverKey"]] = []
    output[l["driverKey"]].append(l)
```